# Transfer with wallet RPC

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc

I have an error when I try to use curl to transfer with a 64 character `payment_id`. The payment ID is being automatically set to 0000000000000 and is only 16 characters long. Whats wrong with my RPC call?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `payment_id` field in `transfer`/`transfer_split` is the same type as used by integrated addresses, i.e. it's a short encrypted ID. It's therefore restricted to 16 characters.

Second, payment IDs are being deprecated, being replaced by subaddresses.

UPDATE

I double checked the current (0.14.0.2) wallet RPC release code and this still allows long payment IDs (64 characters). The second point above still holds - they are being deprecated.

For completeness, the OP also placed the `payment_id` parameter in the wrong place in the JSON payload.

Comment: Thank you for reply and fixed my grammar,
im confused about the payment_id, in the kucoin they have 00000000xxxxxxx custom payment_id with zero in front 16 characters actually got 64 characters. and i try transfer to kucoin address but failed because the payment_id is wrong result is 000000000 only with 16 characters but i already input the payment_id with 64 characters. What should I do ? how to transfer my balance to exchange 64characters from my monero-rpc-wallet ? 

Thank you

Comment: i try send with 16 characters payment_id , when i checked in get_transfer out still "payment_id": "0000000000000000",

Comment: this is my tx id, https://minergate.com/blockchain/xmr/transaction/922adea99863f6b072531625882163601f6f63274fe4d99aeb0a206fa669dc9a
i already input the payment id but still not showing in there,

Comment: my code curl -u user:password --digest -X POST localhost:18083/json_rpc -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"transfer","params":{"destinations":[{"amount":120000000,"address":"address_wallet","payment_id":"1861433210"}],"account_index":0,"subaddr_indices":[0],"priority":1,"ring_size":7,"get_tx_key": true}}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'

Comment: I see the payment ID present and encrypted on a proper blockchain explorer: https://xmrchain.net/search?value=922adea99863f6b072531625882163601f6f63274fe4d99aeb0a206fa669dc9a

Comment: how to make the payment_id not encrypted ? i try transfer from binance to kucoin  here the tx https://minergate.com/blockchain/xmr/transaction/882d32c3d08baeeb65f2a1b1cd551bc6777bc083bb554122035c041dc88191ee the payment id is showing not encrypted, what should i do ?

Comment: solved, wrong curl position of payment_id,

Comment: "solved, wrong curl position of payment_id" <- payload is a json object, position changes nothing.

Comment: thats because payment id inside the destinations , not outside, if outside its works.

Comment: Oh you put it in the wrong object, I missed that.

Comment: yes , i'm wrong position object, i think payment id can inside destination, but its wrong, so how to make multi address & payment id in transfer ?

Comment: payment_id is at the transaction level, not per destination output.